# ELECTRON JS, how to solve packets out of order error

Tags: mysql, node.js

[code main.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QgnF.png) [code database.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCCDE.png)  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0gkW.png)

When I connect to MYSQL, data is retrieved, but I get an error after a certain time.

Whenever I try to establish a mysql connection I get this error. How can I fix this? I looked at every source but couldn't find it.

Comment: It's hard to debug code without seeing code, but my guess is that you're re-using the same connection and send multiple queries over a single connection at the same time.

Comment: Yep, you can't reuse the same `connection`. Use a connection pool instead: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections